# How do achievements work in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, achievements

I'm trying to figure out how to get achievements in Minecraft Beta 1.5. I'm on a multiplayer server, and there's a message that says `Press 'I' to open your inventory` in the top-right corner. However, when I open my inventory, nothing happens.

Looking at the Achievements page in the game menu, `Taking Inventory` is highlighted and blinking, and no other achievements appear to be available for collection. Is there a step I'm missing, like selecting the achievement somehow? Or does it just not work yet?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently you have to load single-player first, and get the very first achievement. After that, achievements will work fine in both single-player and multiplayer.

Comment: Yeah this is a known bug on the Wiki.. Do the first achievement in Single Player... Also if you fail to get an achievement it suggests trying it again in a new world.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there is a problem with your achievements file in the `.minecraft` folder; try deleting it.